# center the button

Tags: google-apps-script

Such code works for Label:

```
function doGet() {
 var app = UiApp.createApplication().setStandardsMode(true);
 return app.add(app.createLabel('centered').setStyleAttributes(
     {marginLeft: 'auto',
      marginRight: 'auto',
      width: '100px'}));
}
```

But it for button it doesn't work. It doesn't center the button. Why and how make it works?

Comment: You should also mention that this issue shows up only with IE, the code works fine on chrome, firefox & Safari.

Comment: @Serge insas, for button it doesn't

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding display:block to the styles

Just to add: these aren't Apps Script specific hacks per se... this is just standard CSS. You can use the Mozilla Developer Network as a resource for learning more about how different elements react to different CSS.

Also, all Gui Builder components have display:block implicitly set for them (that's how it does the layouts).